# User registration with React, Axios and PHP backend

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, axios, fetch

I need to register a new user with API. Back-end developer gave me screenshot how he implemented registration on PhP. Unfortunately, he doesn't know react so he can't help me. I already have input forms saving them in state. Could you please help me what's going on in the picture below and how make registration on React.

[image]

and my code. Let me know if I missing any field. I have url , but I dont know where to add user/create, company/create links:

```
signUp(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    const formdata = new FormData()
    formdata.append("email", this.state.userLogin.email)
    formdata.append("password", this.state.userLogin.password)
    formdata.append("name", this.state.userLogin.name)
    formdata.append("companyName", this.state.userLogin.companyName)
    formdata.append("region", this.state.userLogin.region)
    axios
      .post("http://dev.***********.com/", formdata)
      .then(res => {
        if (res.data) {
          console.log('success')
          this.props.history.push("/settings")
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
```

Comment: Please, never ever post photos of code.

Comment: @TobiasWilfert I mentioned I only have screenshot of code

Comment: Just because you only have a screenshot doesn't mean we only need to have one. You could do us a favor and type it over.

Comment: What is your problem exactly with this request ?

Comment: you append multiple times the same key `password` with different values, you have to modify that to store name and region.

Comment: also, companyName doesn't seem to get used in the backend. and there are also fields label, label_short you didn't provide on your side

Comment: It would also seem we are missing line terminators.

Comment: You can add the code here..not the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

you are missing some fields for the post request,
but this is how I would do it:

```
const data = {
  username: YOU_NEED_THIS,
  label: YOU_NEED_THIS,
  label_short: YOU_NEED_THIS,

  email: this.state.userLogin.email,
  password: this.state.userLogin.password,
  name: this.state.userLogin.name,
  companyName: this.state.userLogin.companyName,
  region: this.state.userLogin.region,
};

axios
  .post("http://dev.***********.com/", data)
  .then(.....)
```